# How to access attribute of attribute of object in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Say I want to access an object that is called post. Post has a instance variable called Category of type Category.

In the Java controller class

```
model.addAttribute("posts", postRepository.findPostsByUser(user));
```

In the thymeleaf html file I have

```
<tr data-th-each="post : ${posts}">
```

I am wondering if it is it possible to access the below?

```
{post.category.name}
```

For clarification I have included the java classes below. Each instance has associated setters and getters.

```
@Entity
public class Post {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;


@Entity
public class Category {

private String name;
```

Comment: Did you try `{post.category.name}` what was the result?

Comment: This is an error on my part. The variable was not initialized as it was showing as null

Comment: What kind of error did you got? Maybe `LazyLoadingException` issue?

Answer (score 1):

you have to make a condition:

```
<tr th:each="post:${posts}">
    <td th:text="${post.category}!=null? ${post.category.name}:''"></td>
</tr>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your entity code

```
@Entity
public class Post {

   private Category category;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
   public Category getCategory () {
     return this.category;
   }

   public void setCategory (Category category ) {
     this.category = category ;
   }

}
```

you need implement thymeleaf html page as per following

```
<tr th:each="post : ${posts}">
   <td> <span th:utext="{post.category.name}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Hope its help to you!